# VeeValidate localization "Property 'locale' does not exist on type 'Validator'."

Tags: localization, vue.js

I'm using VeeValidate and works perfectly for English (which is default)
however if I try to use any other language I'm getting an error saying 
"Property 'locale' does not exist on type 'Validator'."

Here is my code:

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import french from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/fr';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

@Component
export default class TestTest extends Vue {
locale: any; // I have tried locale: string='fr';

nextLocale() {
  return this.locale === 'en' ? 'French' : 'English';
}

changeLocale() {
  this.locale = this.$validator.locale === 'fr' ? 'en' : 'fr';
  this.$validator.setLocale(this.locale);
}    

 created() {
  this.$validator.updateDictionary({
  fr: {
    messages: french.messages,
  }
})
}

 // other none related code...

}
```

Comment: Looks to me like it's defined in the [latest version of the types](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/b916e2a28b7c4126fe26312babbc22e412a8c384/types/vee-validate.d.ts#L67.json). Are you using a different version?

Comment: just updated to the latest version, still the same... @Bert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:
http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/localization.html#api

To dynamically change the locale in your component, you have to call localize like so

```
this.$validator.localize('fr', french)
```

And it should work just fine (you don't need to call updateDictionary as the call above is already doing this)